# Japanese 'SU' hotel room classification - enough for two people?

Tags: japan, hotels

My partner and I are trying to book a hotel in Japan.
The room categories for the hotel we want are:

- `SB`= Single with bath
- `SU`= Single use of a twin/double with bath
- `TB`= Twin with bath

Is `SU` going to be OK for two people sharing a double?

Answer (score 7):

**Basically, No.**

A Single Use or **SU** room is for 1 person who wishes to stay in a room with a double bed instead of a single bed (i.e. it's a *single* occupancy room). You should either get a **TB** i.e. Double use of a twin room with bath or get two separate rooms.

Comment: @pnuts There's no physical difference. It's only hotel pricing policy. Two people means more resources they need to spend (extra towels, toiletries etc.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the resources are irrelevant, what matters is that SU is specifically intended to give a double room to a single person without making them pay for a double.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Wouldn't a SU be more expensive than a SB? By virtue of the fact that it's a larger room? Then it should be about the same cost as a TB wherein the hotel would like people wishing to live in a SU to not pay extra for a TB because a TB is meant for two people instead of one.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the SU category is not really for people wishing to have a larger room, but to deal with the case where there are more single travellers than actual single rooms. As a hotel, you don't want to charge them the full price of a double room because that would seem unfair (it's not their fault you don't have enough single rooms). But of course you still want to charge fully when there are two people in the room!

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt That's certainly possible as well! Different concepts, same result.

Comment: So the summary version is: A SU is physically capable of hosting two guests, but it would be a violation of hotel policy, and would likely incur additional fees if found out. Right?

Comment: @Flimzy Absolutely.